# How to enable Slider Windows Phone Ticks property

Tags: slider, windows-phone

Here's what i want to do:

```
<Slider Minimum="1" Maximum="100" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Ticks="10,20,50,75,100" />
```

But here's the message Visual Studio display when on "IsSnapToTickEnable":
"The member IsSnapToTickEnabled is not recognized or is not accesible."

The same for Ticks. Why can't i use this feature in Windows Phone ?

Thanx

---

```
private void SliderValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        //Get The new value
        int newValue = (int)e.NewValue;

        //Set the new position
        SliderAmount.Value = newValue;
    }
```

The slider will go to position set as Value.
(In my example my slider parameters are Minimum="1" Maximum="5" SmallChange="1")

Comment: Because Silverlight is only a subset of WPF. The property isn't available on the Silverlight version of the control: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Controls.Slider_properties(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Any alternative ? Can i move the slider manually (via code) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my answer:

```
private void SliderValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        //Get The new value
        int newValue = (int)e.NewValue;

        //Set the new position
        SliderAmount.Value = newValue;
    }
```

The slider will go to position set as Value.
(In my example my slider parameters are Minimum="1" Maximum="5" SmallChange="1")

Comment: Even better solution:  `int newValue = (int)Math.Round( e.NewValue );`

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your posting, which I found after many non working solutions. I was surprised that using discrete values this isn't a property of the slider and that a property like Ticks="1,2,3,4,5" won't work in a Windows Phone either. I found that it is important to warp the `SliderAmount.Value =` line in a Try-Catch because my emulator originally didn't even start the program anymore after adding the code. In the debugger I found that this was a `System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code` error (apparently on first init or something) and the Try/Catch solved that.